# How save request page

Tags: bash, iptables

I use iptables and bash scripts and wanting to make simply HotSpot for self. How to save request page on linux (CentOS)?  Can anybody solved this problem earlier?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Its unclear what you're asking.  Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `iptables` works reasonably well for creating a *firewall*. A *hotspot* is a vastly different concept, and is not likely to be doable with `iptables`. And what that has to do with a request page (whatever that is) is beyond me...

Answer (score 0):

May be logging your requests in iptables, like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix ' INPUT TCP ' --log-level 4
```